# Start button not working in my tkinter program

Tags: python, tkinter

In this practice program, I have created a Color Game. In this I have created a Button called Start Game. Game should start only after I press Start Game button. This button also disappears when game starts. It works perfectly first time. But when countdown gets over or when the player lose, Start Game button should reappear in same place. Start Button is reappearing, but it is calling the function as it should be. please anyone help?

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *

doc = open("Highscore.txt", "r")
us = 0
hs = int(doc.read())
time_count = 5
colorlist = ["Red", "Yellow", "Blue", "Green", "Orange", "Purple"]

def add_uscore():
    global us
    us+= 1
    score.config(text=(f"Score: {us}"))


def add_highscore():
    global us
    global hs
    if us>hs:
        hs = us
        highscore.config(text=(f"Highscore: {hs}"))
        doc2 = open("Highscore.txt","w")
        doc2.write(str(hs))
        doc2.close()


def start_game():
    global colorlist
    global textcolor
    rancolor = choice(colorlist)
    textcolor = choice(colorlist)
    start_btn.grid_forget()
    color.config(text=rancolor, fg=textcolor)
    btn1.config(state=ACTIVE, bg="Indian Red")
    btn2.config(state=ACTIVE, bg="Gold")
    btn3.config(state=ACTIVE, bg="DodgerBlue3")
    btn4.config(state=ACTIVE, bg="Sea Green")
    btn5.config(state=ACTIVE, bg="Dark Orange")
    btn6.config(state=ACTIVE, bg="Purple3")
    timer.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=3)


def countdown():
    global time_count
    if time_count > 0:
        time_count -= 1
        timer.config(text=(f"Countdown: {time_count}"))
        timer.after(1000, countdown)
    elif time_count==0:
        result.config(text="Time Over", fg="Indian Red")
        finish_game()


def finish_game():
    timer.grid_forget()
    start_btn.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=3)
    btn1.config(state=DISABLED)
    btn2.config(state=DISABLED)
    btn3.config(state=DISABLED)
    btn4.config(state=DISABLED)
    btn5.config(state=DISABLED)
    btn6.config(state=DISABLED)


def new_game():
    global us
    us = 0
    score.config(text=(f"Score: {us}"))
    finish_game()


def reset_game():
    global hs
    hs = 0
    doc2 = open("Highscore.txt","w")
    doc2.write(str(hs))
    doc2.close()
    new_game()


def check(ucolor):
    global textcolor
    global time_count
    if textcolor==ucolor:
        result.config(text="Good", fg="Sea Green")
        add_uscore()
        add_highscore()
        start_game()
        time_count = 5
    else:
        result.config(text="You Lose", fg="Indian Red")
        finish_game()



win = Tk()
win.title("Color Game")

#MENU
menu1 = Menu(win)
win.config(menu=menu1)

options = Menu(menu1)
menu1.add_cascade(label="Option", menu=options)
options.add_command(label="New Game", command=new_game)
options.add_command(label="Reset Game", command=reset_game)
options.add_command(label="Exit Game", command=quit)


#DISPLAY
color = Label(win, text="", font=("Comic Sans", 50), anchor=W)
color.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4)

#BUTTON

btn1 = Button(win, text="Red", height=10, width=10, state=DISABLED, command=lambda:check("Red"))
btn1.grid(row=1, column=0)

btn2 = Button(win, text="Yellow", height=10, width=10,state=DISABLED, command=lambda:check("Yellow"))
btn2.grid(row=1, column=1)

btn3 = Button(win, text="Blue", height=10, width=10, state=DISABLED, command=lambda:check("Blue"))
btn3.grid(row=1, column=2)

btn4 = Button(win, text="Green", height=10, width=10, state=DISABLED, command=lambda:check("Green"))
btn4.grid(row=2, column=0)

btn5 = Button(win, text="Orange", height=10, width=10, state=DISABLED, command=lambda:check("Orange"))
btn5.grid(row=2, column=1)

btn6 = Button(win, text="Purple", height=10, width=10, state=DISABLED, command=lambda:check("Purple"))
btn6.grid(row=2, column=2)

#RESULT
result = Label(win, text="", font=("Ariel", 25))
result.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)

#COUNTDOWN
timer = Label(win, text="", fg="Dark Orange", font=("Ariel", 15))

#START BUTTON
start_btn = Button(win, text="START GAME", bg="Green", command= lambda: [start_game(), countdown()])
start_btn.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=3)

#SCORE
score = Label(win, text=(f"Score: {us}"), fg="Sea Green", font=("Ariel", 10))
score.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=3)

#HIGHSCORE
highscore = Label(win, text=(f"Highscore: {hs}"), font=("Ariel", 10), fg="firebrick4")
highscore.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=3)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly is the problem with the start button?

Comment: Please try to reduce this code down to a [mcve]. If the problem is with a specific button, we probably don't need much more code than the button, the function it calls, and enough other code to tie it all together.

Comment: Whenever a player lose or timer is over, game should reset and Start Button should reappear and should work perfectly. But instead, button only reappears but doesn't call the function.

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is a variable `time_count`

It is set as 5 in the beginning of the code

```
...
hs = int(doc.read())
time_count = 5 # <-----------
colorlist = ["Red", "Yellow", "Blue", "Green", "Orange", "Purple"]
...
```

When you run out of time, `time_count` has a value of 0. When you call the `start_game` function again, it sees that `time_count` is 0 and so the game must be over. To fix this, you'd have to reset `time_count` after each time the game ends. Something like this worked for me:

```
def finish_game():
    global time_sleep
    time_sleep = 5
    timer.grid_forget()
    start_btn.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=3)
    btn1.config(state=DISABLED)
    btn2.config(state=DISABLED)
    btn3.config(state=DISABLED)
    btn4.config(state=DISABLED)
    btn5.config(state=DISABLED)
    btn6.config(state=DISABLED)
```

Edit:

I managed to fix the `countdown` function executing on its own in the background by adding a `gameover` variable. When the game ends, it is set to `1`, when the game starts it is again set to `0`. The countdown function checks `gameover` and only executes when it is set to `0`.
I also made the `result` label only appear when the game is over.

The full code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *

doc = open("Highscore.txt", "r")
us = 0
hs = int(doc.read())
time_count = 5
colorlist = ["Red", "Yellow", "Blue", "Green", "Orange", "Purple"]

def add_uscore():
    global us
    us+= 1
    score.config(text=(f"Score: {us}"))


def add_highscore():
    global us
    global hs
    if us>hs:
        hs = us
        highscore.config(text=(f"Highscore: {hs}"))
        doc2 = open("Highscore.txt","w")
        doc2.write(str(hs))
        doc2.close()


def start_game():
    global gameover
    global colorlist
    global textcolor
    gameover = 0
    rancolor = choice(colorlist)
    textcolor = choice(colorlist)
    start_btn.grid_forget()
    result.grid_forget()
    color.config(text=rancolor, fg=textcolor)
    btn1.config(state=ACTIVE, bg="Indian Red")
    btn2.config(state=ACTIVE, bg="Gold")
    btn3.config(state=ACTIVE, bg="DodgerBlue3")
    btn4.config(state=ACTIVE, bg="Sea Green")
    btn5.config(state=ACTIVE, bg="Dark Orange")
    btn6.config(state=ACTIVE, bg="Purple3")
    timer.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=3)


def countdown():
    global time_count
    if time_count > 0 and gameover != 1:
        time_count -= 1
        timer.config(text=(f"Countdown: {time_count}"))
        timer.after(1000, countdown)
    elif time_count==0:
        result.config(text="Time Over", fg="Indian Red")
        finish_game()


def finish_game():
    global time_count
    time_count = 5
    timer.grid_forget()
    result.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
    start_btn.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=3)
    btn1.config(state=DISABLED)
    btn2.config(state=DISABLED)
    btn3.config(state=DISABLED)
    btn4.config(state=DISABLED)
    btn5.config(state=DISABLED)
    btn6.config(state=DISABLED)


def new_game():
    global us
    us = 0
    score.config(text=(f"Score: {us}"))
    finish_game()


def reset_game():
    global hs
    hs = 0
    doc2 = open("Highscore.txt","w")
    doc2.write(str(hs))
    doc2.close()
    new_game()


def check(ucolor):
    global textcolor
    global time_count
    global gameover
    if textcolor==ucolor:
        result.config(text="Good", fg="Sea Green")
        add_uscore()
        add_highscore()
        start_game()
        time_count = 5
    else:
        result.config(text="You Lose", fg="Indian Red")
        gameover = 1
        finish_game()



win = Tk()
win.title("Color Game")

#MENU
menu1 = Menu(win)
win.config(menu=menu1)

options = Menu(menu1)
menu1.add_cascade(label="Option", menu=options)
options.add_command(label="New Game", command=new_game)
options.add_command(label="Reset Game", command=reset_game)
options.add_command(label="Exit Game", command=quit)


#DISPLAY
color = Label(win, text="", font=("Comic Sans", 50), anchor=W)
color.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4)

#BUTTON

btn1 = Button(win, text="Red", height=10, width=10, state=DISABLED, command=lambda:check("Red"))
btn1.grid(row=1, column=0)

btn2 = Button(win, text="Yellow", height=10, width=10,state=DISABLED, command=lambda:check("Yellow"))
btn2.grid(row=1, column=1)

btn3 = Button(win, text="Blue", height=10, width=10, state=DISABLED, command=lambda:check("Blue"))
btn3.grid(row=1, column=2)

btn4 = Button(win, text="Green", height=10, width=10, state=DISABLED, command=lambda:check("Green"))
btn4.grid(row=2, column=0)

btn5 = Button(win, text="Orange", height=10, width=10, state=DISABLED, command=lambda:check("Orange"))
btn5.grid(row=2, column=1)

btn6 = Button(win, text="Purple", height=10, width=10, state=DISABLED, command=lambda:check("Purple"))
btn6.grid(row=2, column=2)

#RESULT
result = Label(win, text="", font=("Ariel", 25))

#COUNTDOWN
timer = Label(win, text="", fg="Dark Orange", font=("Ariel", 15))

#START BUTTON
start_btn = Button(win, text="START GAME", bg="Green", command= lambda: [start_game(), countdown()])
start_btn.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=3)

#SCORE
score = Label(win, text=(f"Score: {us}"), fg="Sea Green", font=("Ariel", 10))
score.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=3)

#HIGHSCORE
highscore = Label(win, text=(f"Highscore: {hs}"), font=("Ariel", 10), fg="firebrick4")
highscore.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=3)

win.mainloop()
```

Notice how the `result` label is only placed with the grid manager when the game ends and it is removed once the game starts again:

Placing the `result` label with `.grid` when the game ends

```
def finish_game():
    ...
    result.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
    ...
```

Removing the `result` label with `.grid_forget` when the game starts

```
def start_game():
    ...
    result.grid_forget()
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I have tried that already, but it is not working for me. It looks like start_game() function not calling at all.

Comment: The function is definitely being called. My code was wrong, though, because i only added "time_sleep = 5" under the countdown function. You need to add "time_sleep = 5" to the finish_game function, so the time is reset both when you run out of time and when you lose the game. Another problem however is that even if finish_game is called, the countdown function keeps being called. I suspect this is because when you lose the game, time_count is never reset to 0, so the countdown function keeps calling itself.